# Why axios does not send request with params?

Tags: node.js, axios

```js
function googleFind(what,where){
  var links = []
  axios
    axios.get(`https://www.google.com/`,{params: {
            "search?q=": what,
          }})
    .then(res => {
      fs.writeFileSync("text.html",res.data)
                 })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
googleFind("Something","znanija.org")
```

The code must send get request:"https://www.google.com/search?q=Something",
but it just ignored "params",
**help pls**

Answer (score 0):

Search should be part of the URL and params should be passed as an object.

```
axios.get('https://www.google.com/search', {
  params: {
    q: what,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank u!!!
Thank u!!!
Thank u!!!
Thank u!!!
I love you!!!